# Creating a class or interface for a complex generic type

Tags: c#, casting, generic-collections

I am trying to create an alias for a type of list of list of object.  Specifically, I want to shorten all the typing I have to do for this type:

```
IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>
```

My attempt is demonstrated here:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyObject
        {
            public static IMyCollection GetCollection()
            {
                var a = new List<MyObject>();
                a.Add(new MyObject());

                var b = new List<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>();
                b.Add(a.AsReadOnly());

                return b.AsReadOnly();
            }
        }

        public interface IMyCollection : IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>
        {
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = MyObject.GetCollection();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't compile.  There error is:

```
    Cannot implicitly convert type
 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<MyApp.Program.MyObject>>'
 to 'MyApp.Program.IMyCollection'.
 An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

OK, so I'm close. Perhaps explicitly casting?  So I change the return statement in `GetCollection` to

```
return (IMyCollection)b.AsReadOnly();
```

That compiles, albeit with a resharper warning: Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection>' and 'MyApp.Program.IMyCollection'

And at runtime, I get an invalid cast exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[MyApp.Program+MyObject]]' to type 'IMyCollection'.

OK, I can accept all that. I'm the last person to ask about stuff like covariance and contravariance and stuff like that.  But surely there's a way to define and create an object with a short name to stand in for a really long named datatype.

How can I create a type with a really long name and cast to a type with a really short name?

UPDATE:
A co-worker suggested using a `using` statement.

```
using IMyCollection= System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<MyApp.Program.MyObject>>;
```

While that would work, it then becomes necessary to do that in every file that uses `IMyCollection`. Not exactly what I would consider a solution to my goal.

Comment: Since you're using `var`, why do you need it to be shorter? You're using list also and just invoking the `AsReadOnly` method

Comment: "I want to save keystrokes," sure seems like a bad reason to change your object model - if what you were attempting were successful you'd disallow me from using any `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>` that didn't happen to be `IMyCollection` in all the places I specified `IMyCollection`, even though your intent is that they are identical.

Comment: @DevEstacion You're focused on the simple example meant only to demonstrate the cast I'm trying to do.  In the real world, that full type must be typed many times over as function return values, passed as parameters to other functions, casting when retrieving from data bags, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How badly do you want this?

You can manually implement your own wrapper class.

```
public interface IMyCollection : IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>
{
}

public class MyCollectionImpl : IMyCollection
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>> _wrappedCollection;
    public MyCollectionImpl(IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>> wrappedCollection)
    {
        _wrappedCollection = wrappedCollection;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get 
        {
            return _wrappedCollection.Count;
        }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<MyObject> this[int index]
    {
        get 
        {
            return _wrappedCollection[index];
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _wrappedCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _wrappedCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you simply create an instance of this:

```
 public class MyObject
    {
        public static IMyCollection GetCollection()
        {
            var a = new List<MyObject>();
            a.Add(new MyObject());

            var b = new List<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>();
            b.Add(a.AsReadOnly());

            return new MyCollectionImpl(b.AsReadOnly());
        }
    }
```

This seems like a lot of extra work, but I would actually consider this a refactoring step.

I believe that the need to pass around types made up of complex set of generic parameters, is actually a *bad smell* in your code.

Ask yourself, what are you actually using `IMyCollection` for? Would you be able to add some specialized methods to this interface to make it easier to use?

Once you've created your own `MyCollectionImpl` class you can slowly add a number of methods to your `IMyCollection` interface to simplify it's usage. At some point, you might even get to the stage where you can stop exposing the `<IReadonlyList<IReadonlyList<MyObject>>` interface.

Comment: This is pretty much what I had in mind.  It is indeed a refactoring for my code, one small step at a time adding features as they are needed.  My question was intended to find a step between just using the complex type and your implementation of MyCollectionImpl.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with covariance. `IMyCollection` inherits from `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>` so you can cast an instance of `IMyCollection` to `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>` but not the other way around.

If you wanna have some custom conversions then you can create a type instead with the short name you want and declare a conversion from `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<MyObject>>` to your type using [`operator overloading`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx). This really seems unnecessary and unusual way to use operator overloading but it's the only way to do what you want to achieve.